# Accessing custom property's value gives 'Out of Memory' error when value is null

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a custom property in an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) sheet, then retrieve its value.  This is fine when I don't use an empty string, i.e. `""`.  When I use the empty string, I get this error:

```
Run-time error '7':
Out of memory
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub proptest()

Dim cprop As CustomProperty
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("control")
sht.CustomProperties.Add "path", ""

For Each cprop In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("control").CustomProperties
    If cprop.Name = "path" Then
        Debug.Print cprop.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The code fails at `Debug.Print cprop.value`.  Shouldn't I be able to set the property to `""` initially?

Comment: It looks like you can't. I tried a few workarounds - xl2010 - such as `sht.CustomProperties.Add "path", Application.Trim(" ")` and then `cprop.Value = vbNullString` but it doesn't look like a zero length value is acceptable.

Comment: Same for Excel 2003. Note that you cannot even do this manually via the File|Properties|Custom dialog. The "Add" button is grayed out until you enter at least one character.

Comment: @sigil in this case you probably should have posted a follow-up answer to your own question. I posted comments leaving the door open in case someone else could find a solution/explantion. K_B has summarised my comments and posted as an answer - which didn't add to this question.

Comment: @brettdj My answer won't add any more than K_B's.  I accepted K_B's answer because it was correct, and would have accepted your comment had you posted it as an answer.  Because K_B more or less copied your comment, i'd say you have prior art; if you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.  If you want to talk more about this issue, that's a discussion that should happen in Meta.

Comment: @sigil ok lets leave it as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from the comments and the answer from Daniel Dusek it is clear that this cannot be done. The property should have at least 1 character to be valid, an empty string just isnt allowed and will give an error when the .Value is called.

So you `Add` this property with a length 1 or more `string` and you `Delete` the property again when no actual value is to be assigned to it.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 2):

With **vbNullChar** it works, sample:

```
Sub proptest()
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("control")

  ' On Error Resume Next
  sht.CustomProperties.Item(1).Delete
  ' On Error GoTo 0

  Dim pathValue As Variant
  pathValue = vbNullChar

  Dim pathCustomProperty As CustomProperty
  Set pathCustomProperty = sht.CustomProperties.Add("path", pathValue)

  Dim cprop As CustomProperty
  For Each cprop In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("control").CustomProperties
      If cprop.Name = "path" Then
          Debug.Print cprop.Value
      End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: it does. But vbNullChar is not zero length.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned it is not possible to set empty strings.

An easy workaround is to use a magic word or character, such as `~Empty` (or whatever seems proof enough for you):

```
Dim MyProperty As Excel.CustomProperty = ...
Dim PropertyValue As String = If(MyProperty.Value = "~Empty", String.Empty, MyPropertyValue)
```

A slightly more expensive workaround but 100% safe is to start all the values of your custom properties with a character that you then always strip off. When accessing  the value, systematically remove the first character:

```
Dim MyProperty As Excel.CustomProperty = ...
Dim PropertyValue As String = Strings.Mid(MyProperty.Value, 2)
```

You can write an extension to make your life easier:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Function ValueTrim(MyProperty as Excel.CustomProperty) As String
    Return Strings.Mid(MyProperty.Value, 2)
End Function
```

Now you can use it like this: `Dim MyValue As String = MyProperty.ValueTrim`

Use a reversed principle when you add a custom property:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Function AddTrim(MyProperties As Excel.CustomProperties, Name As String, Value As String) as Excel.CustomProperty
    Dim ModifiedValue As String = String.Concat("~", Value) 'Use ~ or whatever character you lie / Note Strig.Concat is the least expensive way to join two strings together.
    Dim NewProperty As Excel.CustomProperty = MyProperties.Add(Name, ModifiedValue)      
    Return NewProperty 
End Function
```

To use like this: `MyProperties.AddTrim(Name, Value)`

Hope this helps other people who come across the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers and some trial and error, I wrote a class to wrap a `Worksheet.CustomProperty`.

### WorksheetProperty:Class

Sets and Gets the value of a `Worksheet.CustomProperty` and tests if a `Worksheet` has the `CustomProperty`

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
Attribute VB_Name = "WorksheetProperty"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
'@Folder("Classes")
'@PredeclaredId

Option Explicit
Private Type TMembers
    Name As String
    Worksheet As Worksheet
End Type
Private this As TMembers

Public Property Get Create(pWorksheet As Worksheet, pName As String) As WorksheetProperty
    With New WorksheetProperty
        Set .Worksheet = pWorksheet
        .Name = pName
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As WorksheetProperty
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Property Get Worksheet() As Worksheet
    Set Worksheet = this.Worksheet
End Property

Public Property Set Worksheet(ByVal pValue As Worksheet)
    Set this.Worksheet = pValue
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = this.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(ByVal pValue As String)
    this.Name = pValue
End Property

Public Property Get Value() As String
    Dim P As CustomProperty
    For Each P In Worksheet.CustomProperties
        If P.Name = Name Then
            Value = P.Value
            Exit Property
        End If
    Next
End Property

Public Property Let Value(ByVal pValue As String)
    Delete
    Worksheet.CustomProperties.Add Name:=Name, Value:=pValue
End Property

Public Property Get hasCustomProperty(pWorksheet As Worksheet, pName As String) As Boolean
    Dim P As CustomProperty
    For Each P In pWorksheet.CustomProperties
        If P.Name = pName Then
            hasCustomProperty = True
            Exit Property
        End If
    Next
End Property


Public Sub Delete()
     Dim P As CustomProperty
    For Each P In Worksheet.CustomProperties
        If P.Name = Name Then
            P.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

### Usage

I have several properties of my custom Unit class return a WorksheetProperty.  It makes it really easy to sync my database with my worksheets.

```
Public Function hasMeta(Ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    hasMeta = WorksheetProperty.hasCustomProperty(Ws, MetaName)
End Function

Public Property Get Id() As WorksheetProperty
    Set Id = WorksheetProperty.Create(this.Worksheet, "id")
End Property

Public Property Get CourseID() As WorksheetProperty
    Set CourseID = WorksheetProperty.Create(this.Worksheet, "course_id")
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As WorksheetProperty
    Set Name = WorksheetProperty.Create(this.Worksheet, "unit_name")
End Property
```

### Simple Usage

```
'ActiveSheet has a CustomProperty
Debug.Print WorksheetProperty.hasCustomProperty(ActiveSheet, "LastDateSynced")

'Set a CustomProperty
WorksheetProperty.Create(ActiveSheet, "LastDateSynced").Value = Now

'Retrieve a CustomProperty
Debug.Print WorksheetProperty.Create(ActiveSheet, "LastDateSynced").Value
```